# How do I enable the Theme developer module in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I am working with drupal 7.4, and have installed the Devel module; however, I am missing the "Enable theme developer" link in its menu.

Is there anything I have overlooked here?

Comment: How did you installed it? I can't find no where the instruction on how to install the devel module. I have never installed a module. I am new to Drupal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for the [Theme developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module, which is now a separate module from the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module?

Comment: +1: since I probably am.  In the tutorial I was doing it still was part of devel.  I accept your answer as soon as I have time to test it out.

Comment: The two modules have been split some time ago, but once the Devel module contained it.

Answer (score 1):

its too late to answer. but it may help some newbies. if your are looking for [Theme Developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module. It is now a separate module and it relies on 
[Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and [simplehtmldom](http://drupal.org/project/simplehtmldom).

--cheers

Comment: I guess that's the same answer as the accepted one, I would mention the simplehtmldom in a comment on that answer